# PHP - Is there a way to differentiate when magic method is called through a PHP construct or directly?

Tags: php, magic-methods

in PHP, is there is there a way to differentiate when magic method is called through a PHP construct or directly?

E.g.: `public function __clone() {}` is called each time an object is cloned through the `clone` keyword:

```
$a = new ObjectA();
$clone = clone $a; // Calls __clone()
```

However, someone can even (do not know why someone should do that, but, anyway) call `__clone()` directly:

```
$a = new ObjectA();
$clone = $a->__clone(); // Call __clone() directly
```

Same goes for other PHP magic methods (`__call()`, `__debugInfo`, etc.).

Can we differentiate between the two cases somehow?

Thank you for the attention!

**EDIT**: Assume the following scenario:

I have a dynamic proxy class, which extends a base class and internally creates an instance of the base class only when the object is effectively used:

```
class A {
   ...
   public function __clone() {
      echo "clone A!!!";
   }
   ...
}

class DynamicProxy extends A {

   protected $a = NULL;

   public function __clone() {
      $this->createA();
      if ( /* __clone() is triggered by `clone $obj`, I need to clone $a: */ )  {
        clone $this->a;
      }
      else {
        // But if someone, for some reason (I do not now why, but it could be, and I would like to be consistent), have called `$obj->__clone();`, I do not have to call `clone $obj`, but proxy the call:
        return $this->a->__clone();
      }

   }

   protected function createA() {
      if (is_null($this->a)) {
        $this->a = new A();
      }
   }
}

$obj = new DynamicProxy();
```

Comment: Why would you? A method should not behave differently depending on who called it.

Comment: I am building a dynamic proxy which extends a base class, overrides all its methods and then proxies the call to an internal instance of the base class. If there's a `__clone()` or another magic method called on the proxy, I need to know whether it has been called directly (for some reasons I don't know). If it has been called directly, I would have to call it directly within my proxy `__clone()` without cloning the internal instance through `clone`, if not, I need to `clone` the internal instance with the `clone` keyword. This is to be consistent with the caller's code.

Comment: I think the simpler and more consistent solution would be to define *one* behaviour for `__clone` and simply disallow the other behaviour. E.g. `clone $proxy` always creates a clone of the wrapped object wrapped in a new proxy.

Comment: You are right, however, I do not know why someone could call `__clone()` directly. Yet, there's the possibility and I would, of course if possible, be consistent with the caller's code. I posted an edit explaining better what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If you don't have a concrete use case (you don't know why someone would do this), then don't try to cater to that undefined use case.

Comment: OK, thank you! Anyway, if you know a way to do it, please, write an answer! I thought about using `debug_backtrace()`, but it seems that both `clone $obj` and `$obj->__clone()` have the same call stack.

Comment: `clone` is a keyword, not a function. That's why it does not appear in the output of `debug_backtrace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Many of your assumptions are incorrect, one can not call `__clone()` directly and get a clone of the object to be returned because [the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone) says:

```
void __clone ( void )
```

and

> An object's __clone() method cannot be called directly.

It is a bit misleading because it can actually be called, but the result is like calling any other object's method, and will not make a clone of the original object.

Consider this snippet:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    function __construct($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    function __clone() {
        echo "I'm a clone";
    }

    function getX() {
        echo $this->x;
    }
}

$a = new Foo('foo');
$b = $a->__clone(); # > I'm a clone
var_dump($b);       # > NULL
$b->getX();         # Exception: Call to a member function getX() on null

?>
```

`__clone` method is called **on newly created, clone object** after it has been cloned. It's more like a callback and it does not produce a clone.

Maybe it would be better if PHP threw an exception when someone tried to call `__clone` directly, but there are many things PHP could do better.

What you can do is to deeply test if what you think is possible is really possible.